# Todd class as an Euler class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, loop-spaces

Let $X$ be a relatively nice scheme or topological space.

In various physics papers I've come accross, the Todd class $\text{Td}(T_X)$ is viewed as the Euler class of the normal bundle to $X\to LX$. Here $LX$ is the loop space of $X$. They usually call it $e_{reg}$, the regularised Euler class.

**Question:** Is there a way of making this notion of regularised Euler class rigorous?

Whatever the correct definition is, it should work for

- finite dimension vector bundles, where it reduces to usual notion of Euler class,
- loop spaces, where it reduces to the Todd class.

Comment: Could you include a reference or give a little more context for this "regularized euler class"  ?

Comment: @kiran Of course. This comes up a lot in papers of Rongmin Lu, e.g. "Regularized Equivariant Euler Classesand Gamma Functions", section 6 https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/50479/8/02whole.pdf

Comment: I suspect this might still be unknown: see Atiyah's paper "Circular symmetry and stationary-phase approximation", where it's apparent that these sorts of questions are still not rigorously solved (and Brylinski's more recent book on loop spaces where he repeats this).

Comment: There's a version of this question in derived algebraic geometry (explaining the Todd genus and Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch via derived versions of loop spaces) that's well understood - the idea is due to a visionary but hard to understand paper of Markarian https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610553, a related story is explained in https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.7175 and the final derivation of the Todd genus is due to Kondyrev and Prikhodko https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00172 --- see also closely related https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03589 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00879.

Comment: You might also want to look at the closely related literature deriving the Witten and A^ genus from [rigorous mathematical] quantum field theory - see Costello on the Witten genus https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5422, and Grady-Gwilliam and Grady on the A^ genus https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3533 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6816

Comment: Always unpleasant to mention a paper one has contributed to, but something very close to an answer to the original question can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.14945.pdf . There, only the Witten class case is treated in detail as we considered Atiyah's treatment in "Circular symmetry and stationary-phase approximation" to be complete for the Todd class. Yet, the details on the Todd class case in the spirit of our paper can be found in Mattia Coloma's thesis.

Comment: @domenicofiorenza Thanks! Could you point to the most relevant section(s)?

Comment: I'd say Sections 2 and 6. In Section 6 you'll have to replace every occurrence of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ with $\mathbb{R}/\Lambda$ or ask Mattia for a copy of his thesis, where you can find the computation spelled out in detail

Comment: @domenicofiorenza I've had a look and I'm a bit worried by the fact that your top chern classes (of the normal bundle of $X$ inside $LX$) are defined by hand like in Atiyah's original paper, rather than follow from some more general notion of euler class, from which the formal Weierstrass-regularisation type formulas also fall out.

Comment: @Pulcinella Well, in the finite dimensional case that is the definition of equivariant Chern classes. In the infinite dimensional case the finite dimensional formulas become infinite products and one has to make sense of them. So the real question, I guess, is what singles out the zeta-regularization among the possible ways of giving a meaning to those infinite products? Surely zeta-regularization has good properties (see, e.g., the paper by Quine,Heydari and Song), but I do not know how to completely avoid an element of choice making it absolutely canonical.

Comment: @domenicofiorenza That's a good question! It was part of what I was getting at originally. A question I might have for you is if you know whether 1. this regularised Euler class might fit into a Gysin sequence, or 2. if it satisfies a formula like $i^*i_*=e(N_i)$ for $i:X\to LX$. Obviously $i_*$ is undefined at the moment, but ignore that for now...

Comment: Also I'd be curious whether you think it's necessary to work equivariantly to get an answer. The Atiyah paper worked non equivariantly, but a lot of their intermediate algebra makes it look like equivariant setup is the one to use.

Comment: @Pulcinella The two questions are indeed related: in finite dimensions in the equivariant setting, after localization both $e(N_i)$ and $i^*$ become invertible, so that one can define $i_*$ from the formula $i^*i_*=e(N_i)$. This is another of the reasons inducing me to think that the equivariant setting is the correct one to handle the Euler class of the normal bundle to $i\colon X\to LX$. For Gysin I admit I have never thought to that: it is a very good question!

Comment: You can define $i_*$ for any closed embedding between smooths actually, and $i^*i_*=e$ is still true.